# How can I not to receive UITextView's delegate message since delete(backspace) action in iOS7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uitextview

I use the following delegate to receive any keyboard changing actions. There was no problem until iOS 6 so far, but I came up against one problem in iOS 7.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
```

My app should support Korean language.

I can explain the problem using simple example to understand it easily.

[Action Flow]
  1) '러러' is showed in UITextView now.
  2) an user touches delete key once.
  3) '러러' is changed to '럴'.

I expect to be called [(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView] just one time.
**It works well under iOS 6!**

In iOS 7, however, the delegate is called **three times** like that flow

'러러' --> '러'
  '러' --> empty
  empty --> '럴'

my app is dealing with carefully the delegate to control text contents of UITextView. Therefore, I don't want to receive a delegate message about intermediate steps.

Simply, I really want to use UITextView and its delegate same to the way that it works under iOS 6.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in UITextView, open a radar and get feedback from the apple engineers.http://radar.apple.com/

Comment: Can you tell where you have set delegate in your code?

Comment: @sathiamoorthy There is a viewcontroller who has one UITextView. the viewcontroller is set as UITextView's delegate. and It also has implementation of UITextView's delegates.

Comment: No. I am asking, whether it is in ViewDidLoad or cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(methodNothing)
 name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
 object:firstName];
```

and you can use:`UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification` or `UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification`

Comment: don't forget to remove the observer

Comment: Notifications work same to delegates. I need to ignore intermediate process.